# Run function only once until onmouseout

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, anchor

I have an anchor tag that plays a sound everytime the link is hovered:

```
<a onmouseenter="playAudio();">LINK</a>
```

However, when hovered, the link creates some characters that, if I keep moving the mouse inside the element, it keeps playing the sound over and over again.

Is there a way to play the `onmouseenter` function only once until it has detected the event `onmouseout`?

I've tried adding:

```
<a onmouseenter="playAudio();this.onmouseenter = null;">LINK</a>
```

but then it only plays the sound once.

Here goes the TextScramble animation function:

```js
// ——————————————————————————————————————————————————
// TextScramble
// ——————————————————————————————————————————————————

class TextScramble {
  constructor(el) {
    this.el = el
    this.chars = '!<>-_\\/[]{}—=+*^?#________'
    this.update = this.update.bind(this)
  }
  setText(newText) {
    const oldText = this.el.innerText
    const length = Math.max(oldText.length, newText.length)
    const promise = new Promise((resolve) => this.resolve = resolve)
    this.queue = []
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      const from = oldText[i] || ''
      const to = newText[i] || ''
      const start = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40)
      const end = start + Math.floor(Math.random() * 40)
      this.queue.push({
        from,
        to,
        start,
        end
      })
    }
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameRequest)
    this.frame = 0
    this.update()
    return promise
  }
  update() {
    let output = ''
    let complete = 0
    for (let i = 0, n = this.queue.length; i < n; i++) {
      let {
        from,
        to,
        start,
        end,
        char
      } = this.queue[i]
      if (this.frame >= end) {
        complete++
        output += to
      } else if (this.frame >= start) {
        if (!char || Math.random() < 0.28) {
          char = this.randomChar()
          this.queue[i].char = char
        }
        output += `<span class="dud">${char}</span>`
      } else {
        output += from
      }
    }
    this.el.innerHTML = output
    if (complete === this.queue.length) {
      this.resolve()
    } else {
      this.frameRequest = requestAnimationFrame(this.update)
      this.frame++
    }
  }
  randomChar() {
    return this.chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.chars.length)]
  }
}

// ——————————————————————————————————————————————————
// Configuration
// ——————————————————————————————————————————————————

const phrases = [
  'MAIN_HUB'
]

const el = document.querySelector('.link_mainhub')
const fx = new TextScramble(el)

let counter = 0
const next = () => {
  fx.setText(phrases[counter]).then(() => {});
}

el.addEventListener('mouseenter', next);
```

```html
<a class="link_mainhub" onmouseenter="playAudio();">LINK</a>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve]. That’s not how `mouseenter` behaves.

Comment: I don't understand why the event is firing multiple times. It should only fire when the mouse first moves into the anchor. Moving the mouse inside the anchor shouldn't fire it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a variable when you start playing the audio, and check for this before playing it again. Have the animation unset the variable when it's done.

```
function audioPlaying = false;
function playAudio() {
    if (!audioPlaying) {
        audioPlaying = true;
        audioEl.play();
    }
}

const next = () => {
  fx.setText(phrases[counter]).then(() => {
    audioPlaying = false;
  });
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer - please see the example here https://www.vtxfactory.org - if you hover over the "Main Hub" and "Projects" buttons, it will randomize the characters (that is the moment when and if you move the mouse inside the element the sound will repeat)

Comment: I understand why the sound plays continuosly, because the element is being updated with the new characters information - is there a way to:

> play the sound on mouseenter > wait that the randomizer finishes > play the sound again

Comment: You should probably attach the mouseenter event to the box, which doesn't move, rather than the text inside it that moves around.

Comment: Also, you should fix the fact that the size of the button flickers while it's randomizing.

Comment: I tried attaching the mouseenter event to the parent element but it still does the same thing

Comment: I don't hear any sound on that site.

Comment: Funny, when I opened DevTools the sound started playing.

Comment: You need to update the question to include the animation code, since that's an important part of the problem. Basically, you need to move the `audioPlaying = false;` to the function that detects the end of the animation. Maybe something like `fx.setText(...).then(() => audioPlaying = false)`

Comment: hey I've added the animation code and config on my post. I have this `fx.setText(phrases[counter]).then(() => {
            };`